# What does it mean by a manga series being licensed, how does it affect online readers, and how can I continue reading it?

Tags: licensing

A while back I was reading *Bleach* on an online reader and I finished the chapter I was on. When I came back to read the next chapter, it said

> The series Bleach has been licensed, it is not available in [site name].

What does it mean by "licensed", and is there a way for a broke person like me to read the rest of *Bleach*? (Unfortunately, the library does not buy new ones anymore.)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a request for illegal and licensed materials. Please consult the [Help Center](http://anime.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) to learn what questions are on-topic on this site.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha, I've edited the question a little to make it sound less like "where do I illegally get manga", and more like a general question about the licensing terms.

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall: Accepted. I'm reopening the question. (Though next time, feel free to cast a reopen vote, and even flag if you feel necessary, those are the correct courses of actions =] )

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An alternative to the local library would be the local corporate bookstore. I've seen kids and teenagers sit around the coffee shop if there is seating, right in front of the shelves if there is not, reading the volumes.

The smaller stores won't let you do this, but I think the bigger ones have a PR reason for letting you do this. I'd imagine the reason being they want you to get used to going to their store. That way when you *do* have some disposable income, you're more likely to buy it from them.

Answer (score 8):

The *Bleach* manga is being published in *Weekly Shōnen Jump*, which belongs to Shueisha Inc. - a major Japanese publisher.

In the case of MangaFox, Shueisha requested the removal of *Bleach*, *Naruto* and *One Piece* from the site (you can read more [here](http://forums.mangafox.me/threads/360895-ANNOUNCEMENT-Removal-of-the-Big-3-Manga)), so I would assume something similar had happened to it as well. For the reference, the holder of the rights to publish *Bleach* in the USA belongs to Viz Media, which has also requested the removal of the series from some of the websites before.

Comment: Thank you for explaining that to me. I guess now I have to persuade one of the librarians to try and buy the new volumes. Sigh